# SWRevealViewController with pragmatical view

Tags: swift, subview, swrevealviewcontroller

i currently developping an app in Swift 2.0, and i use the "SWRevealViewController" library.

My question is simple, do you know if it is possible to use "SWRevealViewController" in a pragmatical view, which is loaded with :

```
view.addsubview(myview)
```

to open the sideMenu ?

Thanks

Comment: Nobody to help me with ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to add rwrevealcontroller to child view container ("container view" in object library) in my storyboard. It should be possible to do it programmatically as well. Hope it helps